# Put docker0 behind NAT

Tags: networking, docker, nat, bridge

I have installed docker with default settings on 3 physical machines. Docker created interface docker0 with default ip 172.17.0.1 in bridge mode.

I expected that this network would be private. Problem is that I cannot ping 172.17.0.1 but i can apring 172.17.0.1. why is this so? I want this network to bi completely private.

```
➜  ~ arping -I eno1 172.17.0.1                                                                         
ARPING 172.17.0.1 from 172.19.20.35 eno1
Unicast reply from 172.17.0.1 [00:19:99:16:3E:24]  0.678ms
Unicast reply from 172.17.0.1 [00:19:99:16:3E:70]  0.685ms
Unicast reply from 172.17.0.1 [70:4D:7B:3D:83:33]  0.687ms
```

Is it safe to run this on corporate network or should I get permission of sysadmins?

Answer (score 0):

The created bridge is private to the host it is running on. Can you verify that the IP 172.17.0.1 is not part of your private/corporate network? It's possible that some other host in your network is responding.

If this is the problem, you should probably use another IP and CIDR for the docker0 bridge. Having clashes between docker internal CIDRs and private/corporate network CIDRs will result in strange and hard to debug behavior inside your containers.

Please read https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/ for details on how to customize these settings.

Comment: 172.17.0.1 is not part of corporate network.

I can see with arping, from responses, MAC address which is same as physical address the docker is bridged to. So it is definitely docker which is responding.

I have also tried to change ip of docker0 but it is same issue.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know why it is responding and if this is the way it is supposed to be. But nevertheless, it should still be private to your host. As long as there is no routing and NAT setup to direct traffic to this bridge, you should be safe to use it as is.

Comment: well. my sysadmins are angry. Also for me its weird. Thank you anyway